# How to add Gravity Forms fields in gform_pre_render()

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I have a multi page Gravity Form that presents a series of questions by way of a radio button.

```
Which of the following would you choose?

    o  Choice #1
    o  Choice #2

    +----------+   +----------+  
    |   BACK   |   |   NEXT   |  
    +----------+   +----------+
```

Each question and choice set is configured using custom fields (Advanced Custom Fields). I'm able to iterate through all of these questions and choices just fine from within the `gform_pre_render` filter and now I want to create the needed Gravity Form fields on the fly.

Specifically, there will be a page field and radio button field for every question.

I really have tried just about every search criteria I can think of on Google and scoured through documentation on Gravity Help, but I just don't see an example of adding fields dynamically.

Can someone shine a light for me? :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a field with `GFFields::create()`. Here's a rough example (assumes you are within the `gform_pre_render` filter.

```
$props = array( 
    'id' => 123,
    'label' => 'My Field Label',
    'type' => 'text'
);
$field = GF_Fields::create( $props );
array_push( $form['fields'], $field );
```

There are probably more properties you will need to specify to get the field working. I would recommend using `print_r()` on an existing field to get an idea of all the properties available. You will also want to make sure your field IDs are unique.

Lastly, in order for data to be captured from these existing fields, you will probably want to also add your dynamic fields via the `gform_pre_validation` filter as well.

Comment: Looks like it might be `GF_Fields` instead of `GFFields`?

Comment: Also seems that `GF_Fields::create()` adds the field to the form. If I do an `array_push()` also there are 2 fields added to the form.

Comment: I used [this code](http://pastie.org/private/xavru5uheqiimc6tned3dg) and got [this form](http://grab.by/REjw). There might be an issue with your code that is causing multiple fields to be added.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but any chance you're still monitoring this @David ? I can add the fields, but I need the output to be sent to the confirmation step as well. These fields aren't being captured.

Comment: See the docs here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_pre_render/ The first example shows all the other hooks required to make sure your dynamic fields are loaded at all the appropriate times.